# Connecting points in scatter plot matlab

Tags: matlab

```
for T=1:11
plot(T,MyCell{1,1:T})
end
```

I stored the values in MyCell and wanted to plot the points so that each point connects to the next but it is not working.

It is still a scatter plot

Comment: try `plot(T,-Rspeed,'-ro');`

Comment: Tried before didn't work

Comment: you'll have to attah a screenshot of the graph scatter plot you have and explain why `'-ro'` "didn't work": what did it produce and hat are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question properly. However, if you have a `cell` array of 11 elements, where each element contains a `double`, and you want a line plot of the element values versus index number, the command to use is

```
plot([MyCell{:}]);
```

Or, if you want dots as well as lines:

```
plot([MyCell{:}], '.-')
```

I hope this is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 1):

because you plot a SINGLE point within each for-loop, try to save result in Rspeed(1:length(T)) within for-loop, THEN plot

Comment: I stored the result in MyCell and plot using plot(T,MyCell{1:T},'-'); But it didn't work

Comment: Tried for T=1:11
plot(T,MyCell{1,1:T})
end

Comment: try for i  MyCell{1, i}=f(T) end  THEN plot(T, MyCell)